# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css'

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$('#someDiv').hover 
  (function(){
    (this).css({'background-color': 'black'});
  }, 
  function(){
     (this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
  }
);
```

Every time I have mouseover (or out) on this `div`, Chrome console gives me back the error in the title. I thought that `div` objects have a `css()` method, and I find this situation really confusing.

Comment: DIV elements don't have a `.css()` method. That method is provided on jQuery objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `(this).css({...});`

You need `$(this).css({...});` to use jQuery.

If jQuery is remapped to something other than `$`, use
`jQuery(this).css({...});`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `$` to `(this)`, i.e. `$(this)`.

Inside your event handler, `this` refers to the original DOM object (`HTMLDivElement`, as the error states), not a jQuery object. Wrapping it using $() will make the `css()` method available because now the underlying DOM object is contained in a jQuery wrapper that exposes other functionality.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S7zd8/1/